# Is there a way to decompress a gz in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, compression, zlib

Having trouble finding a good way to decompress some input data I am being sent. I am using Next.js. Most tutorials I find use `const zlib = require('zlib')` or some such, but I find that syntax does not work for me. How do I import and use a library for decompressing gzip in Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, `npm i pako` did it.

```js
import { Inflate } from "pako";


const zdecompress = (data: string) => {
    const inflate = new Inflate({ to: "string" });
    inflate.push(data, true);
    return inflate.result;
};
```